# How to use cron jobs with php mysql request

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have read many questions here about using mysql in background using php,
and many of them say "use cron jobs",
but how do I use those?
A Google search didn't give me much, so that's why I am asking here...

Comment: You have cpanel istalled on your server

Comment: A Google search didn't give you much? http://bit.ly/Npuu6S The second result is How to Create a Cron Job for Your Website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you're running Linux (which cron runs on), you would do this:

1. Run `crontab -e`
2. If it opened in vi, you'll need to press i before editing. If it opened with nano (it'll have key combinations on the bottom), you can just start editing
3. Add your cron job (details below)
4. Use `Esc` then `:wq<Enter>` to save and quit (vi) or `Ctrl+o`, `Ctrl+x` to save and quit (nano)

The links Senouci posted will help you with the details, but here's an example for running a job at midnight:

```
0 0 * * * php /path/to/file.php
```

OR at reboot:

```
@reboot php /path/to/file.php
```

Note that this method works only if you have shell access. If you're using cPanel, use the control panel there, provided it is allowed.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

that took me 2 seconds

My bad then, here is a link that explains how it can be done under cpanel:

http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron_jobs.htm

Comment: By the way, do you need access to the server to use these cron jobs? Cause my website is hosted on a remote location...

Comment: Yes. You need to have either shell or cpanel access. If you use cPanel, you'll need to use the Cron control panel, if allowed. If you can access the shell, use the method I posted.

Comment: What he's saying is: you will need to have access to the command line tool. I remember that you cannot set it up using cpanel but can be done using plesk. If you want to do it using the command line you will need a dedicated server or VPS. Shared plans are a no no

Comment: It can actually be done using cPanel, but only if the host allows it. I have it set up on a server that my programming team is using, to run database queries every hour (which is essentially what the poster is asking about).